# nth-child alternating layout not working (not skipping cards)

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a section where every `even` card has `margin`, to give it that masonry type effect.

I have two types of cards, they vary only based on the widths they occupy.

In my demo, I have each `sm` card wrapped in the `.customCard__column--sm` class. This class is what differentiates it from the wider card.

In my CSS, I've defined my `even` `.customCard`'s that have the class `.customCard__column--sm` to have `margin`.

However, in my demo, card 4 is using the `nth-child(odd)` css.

Cards 4 and 5 should follow the same pattern as cards 1 and 2.

Why is this happening?

```css
main {
  background: #000000;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* listing */
.listing {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.customCard {
  border: 1px solid  #ffffff;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  height: 300px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .customCard__column--sm:nth-child(odd) .customCard {
    margin-right: 18px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .customCard__column--sm:nth-child(even) .customCard {
    margin-top: 120px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .customCard__column--sm:nth-child(even) .customCard {
    margin-top: 178px;
  }
}
.customCard__column--sm .customCard--large {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<main class="listing">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 d-flex customCard__column customCard__column--sm">
        <article class="customCard">Card 1 (SM)</article>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 d-flex customCard__column customCard__column--sm">
        <article class="customCard">Card 2 (SM)</article>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-12 d-flex customCard__column">
        <article class="customCard customCard--large">Card 3 (LG)</article>
      </div>
 
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 d-flex customCard__column customCard__column--sm">
        <article class="customCard">Card 4 (SM)</article>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 d-flex customCard__column customCard__column--sm">
        <article class="customCard">Card 5 (SM)</article>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

`:nth-child` means "nth child". It doesn't mean "nth child only counting the other features of this selector".

Card 4 is the 5th child (of `<div class="row">`), which is an odd numbered one.

---

You'll need to use markup (e.g. another class name) to handle distinguishing when your sequence resets.

Comment: hm, I think understand the logic around `:nth-child` better post your (and other) explanations. However, you've said I need to use differentiating markup (i.e. another class name) to distinguish between the elements.  I have done this already  in the demo, by using the class `customCard__column--sm` on the elements that I want counting?

Comment: @Freddy — You need to use distinguishing markup *instead* of counting (e.g.  the class, but itself,  should tell you if it should be on the left or right)